# ASP.NET Core: Adding attribute will prevent the debug session from continuing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging

I created an interest rate calculator however I modified the class to specify required and range attributes. When I add them and change my variables to null I get this error

[image: Adding Attribute Error]

This is the `FutureValueModel` class producing the errors

```cs
public class FutureValueModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a monthly investment.")]
    [Range(1, 500, ErrorMessage =
           "Monthly investment amount must be between 1 and 500.")]
    public decimal? MonthlyInvestment { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a yearly interest rate.")]
    [Range(0.1, 10.0, ErrorMessage =
           "Yearly interest rate must be between 0.1 and 10.0.")]
    public decimal? YearlyInterestRate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number of years.")]
    [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage =
           "Number of years must be between 1 and 50.")]
    public int? Years { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're modifying the program while it's running.

Comment: Can you show the code that uses the calling model? Or if you read this post, it may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907221/asp-core-debugging-in-vs-adding-namespace-will-prevent-the-debug-session-from